# Maximal value of an expectation

Tags: probability, expected-value

I've encountered the following problem recently:

> Random variables $X$ and $Y$ are normal, $EX = EY = 0$, $Var(X) = 20$, $Var(Y) = \frac15$. Given that the correlation coefficient $\rho_{X, Y} = - \frac34$, what is the maximal possible value of $E(X^3 Y^3)$?

I know that the answer is $-\frac{297}{4}$, but don't know how to get it.

My attempt was based on assumption that $X + Y$ and $X - Y$ (which is unreasonable, but could be right somehow) are normally distributed random variables too, so I know all moments like $E X^n$, $E Y^n$, $E (X \pm Y)^n$. I was looking for some opportunity to use Cauchy--Schwartz inequality. But I haven't succeeded.

I’ve also tried to use characteristic functions, and didn’t manage to get any further.

Moreover, I’ve proved that $X$ and $Y$ can’t be linearly dependent.

I feel like I missed some trick. Any ideas are appreciated.

UPD: Golden_Ratio has found out that one gets the answer assuming $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal. So now it is left to prove that it is impossible to get a greater value.

Comment: Are you assuming X and Y are jointly normal?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio no

Comment: Ok, because you mentioned your attempts included using the sum and difference is normal (which is not true in general for marginal normals)

Comment: @Golden_Ratio well, I probably thought that a special case like this can lead to the answer somehow.

Comment: Sorry if something is a bit unclear, it’s been almost a month since I tried to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm getting that your bound is attained in the joint normal case

Comment: Double check, but I get that in the joint normal case, we have $E[X^3Y^3]=3\rho(\sigma_x^2\sigma^2_y)^{3/2}(3+2\rho^2)=-297/4$